# @!IsNull is still showing null rows in view

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-formula, domino-designer-eclipse

My Lotus Note application has a 10 row table. In each row has a field, named `cert` until `cert_9`.

These 10 fields will be used in a view, sharing a column, `Certificate`. Column value formula being:

```
cert: cert_1: cert_2: cert_3: cert_4: cert_5: cert_6: cert_7: cert_8: cert_9
```

Not all the fields will be used so I only want the view to **not show** blank rows.
So in view selection formula my formula is:

```
SELECT !@IsNull (cert: cert_1: cert_2: cert_3: cert_4: cert_5: cert_6: cert_7: cert_8: cert_9)
```

But when I test preview in Notes, I can still click the empty row below and it can link me to my form, meaning it didn't work.

[image]

Comment: What version of Domino Designer are you using since you call it Lotus Designer? From version 9 it's called IBM Domino Designer and from version 11 it's called HCL Domino Designer :-)

Comment: i'm using 9.0 so IBM Domino Desinger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm undertanding you correctly, and "aaa" and "fsag" are values from the same document (i.e., you are using the "show multiple values as separate entries" property in the view column -- on the second tab of column properties box, then I think what you want is to adjust the *column* formula (not the *selection* formula) so that it is

```
@Trim(cert: cert_1: cert_2: cert_3: cert_4: cert_5: cert_6: cert_7: cert_8: cert_9)
```

[image: Documentation for @Trim function]